# Connect Visual Studio on Windows to the Process on Linux system

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, remote-debugging

I would like to connect **VS 2019** to a process on the linux system for debugging purposes. (If there is a more convenient way for that, I would like to get to know.)

Firstly, based on the information on this page, https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/linux/connect-to-your-remote-linux-computer?view=msvc-160
I created an ssh server on my Linux machine and I connected VS 2019 to my Linux system via ssh

[Here is the image for VS 2019 ssh connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXlAm.png)

on my Linux machine, I am using a robot in a simulation program (ROS) and C++ code controls it.
Debugging is working on my Linux machine using Visual studio code.

[Here I attached the process using Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57YBz.png)

[Here is the debugging using Visual Studio Code on Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPxnV.png)

However, I would like to connect my VS 2019 to this process for debugging purposes.

For that I open VS 2019 and click the "Attach to Process"

[Here is the picture for clicking to attach process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWN1C.png)

After that , I connected to my Linux machine via SSH in VS 2019 and attached the process as I shown in the following picture.

[Attaching Process to the specific Process ID on Linux machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA4Yu.png)

[Selecting debug code type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTDMD.png)

Then I see a empty screen in VS 2019 shown in following picture.

[After attaching process ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bl406.png)

**Do you have any idea how can I do this? or do you know different and more convenient way?**

Comment: When selecting debug code type, why do you choose managed (.NET) instead of native C++. Is your application written in C# or what?

Comment: even if I select "Native GDB", the same is happening.